# How to use multi-gpu during inference in pytorch framework

Tags: pytorch, multi-gpu

I am trying to make model prediction from unet3D built on pytorch framework. I am using multi-gpus

```
import torch
import os
import torch.nn as nn
os.environ['CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER']='PCI_BUS_ID'
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES']='0,1,2'

model = unet3d()
model = nn.DataParallel(model)
model = model.to('cuda')

result = model.forward(torch.tensor(input).to('cuda').float())
```

But the model still uses only 1 GPU (the first one) and I get memory error.

```
CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 64.00 MiB (GPU 0; 11.00 GiB total capacity; 8.43 GiB already allocated; 52.21 MiB free; 5.17 MiB cached)
```

How shoudl I use Multi-GPUs during inference phase? What is the mistake in my script above?

Answer (score 3):

DataParallel handles sending the data to gpu.

```
import torch
import os
import torch.nn as nn
os.environ['CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER']='PCI_BUS_ID'
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES']='0,1,2'

model = unet3d()
model = nn.DataParallel(model.cuda())

result = model.forward(torch.tensor(input).float())
```

if this doesn't work, please provide more details about `input`.

[EDIT]:

Try this:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    result = model(torch.tensor(input).float())
```

Comment: How do you intend to do multi GPU inference with a batch size of 1? How should pytorch split data across GPUs? This is not possible "out of the box". (should it split the model across GPUs? Should it split the image in half, or in quarters?).

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a Keras snippet that demonstrates this functionality.

Comment: could you check this question please? ty https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74380417/how-to-use-multiple-gpu-at-the-same-time-when-using-models-with-pytorch-and-hugg